# Extract year from YYYYMMDD column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, date, pandas, python-datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame in which I would like to create an additional column containing only the year which I extract from a column in YYYYMMDD format.
When searching the forum I found the `to_datetime` command, but for my case it didn't work.

I tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A','B'],
                   'date' :[20130102,20140511]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

what I get as output is:

```
                           date name   year
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020130102    A   1970
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020140511    B   1970
```

but I would like to get:

```
       date name  year
0  20130102    A  2013
1  20140511    B  2014
```

I also tried it without `to_datetime` as my date is not in exactly in the yyyy-mm-dd format, but also couldn't make it that way.
I hope you can help me with this 'newbie' problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to pass the `format` to `to_datetime`: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d)`

Comment: great, thank you so much! (in the end of your format, a ' is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need, to specify the format in which you're providing the date.

```
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d')
```